# VB.NET 4.5 Application's performance degraded in Windows 10 Operating System

Tags: vb.net

We are using windows based application build on VB.NET 4.5 framework.

Application is taking reference of “C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Xml.dll” to perform xml operation.

We are reading data from xml and drawing it on canvas within panel control. Approx. 70-80 controls needs to be drawn.

Whole process is taking around 3-4 seconds in all other Operating system except Windows 10, In windows 10 it is taking greater than 20 seconds to draw all objects.

I am bit worried is there any other way to build application for Windows 10 why is it behaving like this. ?

Code base and files are same in all Operating system but Windows 10 is creating trouble in performance.

Thanks in advance for your replies. !!

Comment: We need specific information to be able diagnose the issue. Also, have you actually profiled the code to see exactly how long each operation or group of operations takes? It might be one specific thing that is taking time but you wouldn't know if you don't try to find out.

Comment: Taking 20 seconds to draw 80 controls is absurdly long, very hard to write code like that.  This doesn't have anything to do with your project or the OS.  Next one on the list is the anti-malware product, invariable a scourge on programmers' machines that make executable files appear from seemingly no-where.  Temporarily disable it and try again.

Comment: As i mentioned we are reading tags from xml using .Item property containing information related to controls which needs to be drawn on canvas and than drawing is performed. No other operations performed. Performed logging in the code which helps us to identify that reading data from xml file and drawing on canvas is taking time.Time taken for this operation is >20 seconds in Windows 10 and 3-4 seconds in Windows 8 and Windows Server 2012 r2.                   
Not possible to share actual code base but it consist of only tag reading and drawing controls on canvas

Comment: Pl refer below links. Same issue is faced here as well. https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/windows-10-performance-issue-on-net-framework/b7265d2c-273a-438d-ba1e-db560f47de4d
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/windows-10-performance-issue-with-winforms/b71c4112-9f05-458a-8705-0677d42354a7

Comment: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/windows-10-performance-issue-on-net-framework/b7265d2c-273a-438d-ba1e-db560f47de4d

Comment: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/windows-10-performance-issue-with-winforms/b71c4112-9f05-458a-8705-0677d42354a7